# Javascript: Add margin-top to an object, object with other objects is inside object A, multiple objects A on page

Tags: javascript

I have an object (div) which has four elements (with classes) inside.

What I am trying to do: When height of the element A is lower than 40px then add to element B 20px margin-top.

However there are many objects on the page.

```
<div class="list">
  <div class="block">
    <div class="list-name" style="height: 20px">element A</div>
    <div class="div1">another div here</div>
    <div class="div2">another div here</div>
    <div class="product-image-container">element B</div>
  </div>

  <div class="block">
    <div class="list-name" style="height: 50px">element A</div>
    <div class="div1">another div here</div>
    <div class="div2">another div here</div>
    <div class="product-image-container">element B</div>
  </div>

  (...)

</div>
```

So far I tried this. Nevertheless it works only if there are only two elements in the div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.list-name').each(function(index, obj){
    console.log($(obj).height())
    if($(obj).height() < 40)
    {
       $(obj).next('.product-image-container').css('margin-top', 20)
    }
    });


});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next()` only works for the very next element.

Use [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) instead which includes all elements on same level

```
$(obj).siblings('.product-image-container').css('margin-top', 20)
```

---

Or another commonly used pattern is to look up to a common ancestor and `find()` within that parent

```
$(obj).closest('.block').find('.product-image-container').css('margin-top', 20)
```